# Replace ProxyJump in ~/.ssh/config

Tags: ssh

I'm am using `ProxyJump` in my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host jump                                                                          
  User jane                                                                       
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  DynamicForward 1028
Host dev                                                                        
  User bill                                                                      
  HostName 5.6.7.8                                                          
  ProxyJump jump
```

My colleague is using an old version of ssh (which they are unable to update). What would be the equivalent configuration to allow them to connect via the jump host? Would `DynamicForward` still work?

Comment: What version of ssh is your colleague using?

Comment: It's the OSX 10.10 version - ssh 6.x something.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`ProxyJump` was added in OpenSSH 7.3 but is nothing more than a shorthand for using `ProxyCommand`, as in:

```
Host hidden-host
  ProxyCommand ssh proxy-host -W %h:%p
```

If your `ssh` version is even older, you might lack the `-W` option, in which case you can use `nc`, as in:

```
Host hidden-host
  ProxyCommand ssh proxy-host nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: In a terminal/cmd this would look like this: `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh <proxy-host> -W %h:%p" <target>` instead of `ssh -J <proxy-host> <target>`

Comment: Here is an additional good source that talks about using `ProxyCommand` when `ProxyJump` is not available. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

Comment: Also note that when using dynamic proxy host-names ([example](https://serverfault.com/a/975922/470655)), `echo` works in both `ProxyJump` and `ProxyCommand`, but `sed` only works in `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: When you use `ssh -J <proxy-host> <target>`, you will see the process `ssh -W [<target>]:22 <proxy-host>`, which tells me that `-J` is nothing but a syntax sugar.

Comment: The proxyCommand is interpreted by the shell, so not only `echo` and `sed` will work, but also any command such as `ruby`. If you set Host to be `<proxy-host>~*` (dynamic), then you can configure ProxyCommand as: `ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | ruby -pe '$_.sub!(/~.*/,"")') -W $(echo %h | ruby -pe '$_.sub!(/.*~/,"")'):%p`