# How to connect to SSH server behind another server?

Tags: ssh, proxy

I have three servers in my project. Server A has a public IP address (`11.11.11.11/24`), Server B has both public and private addresses (`22.22.22.22/24`, `10.10.10.22/24`) and Server C only has a private IP address (`10.10.10.33/24`).

You can see that Server B and Server C are in the same private LAN.

[image]

Now my requirement is for Server A to connect to Server C. It would then run some commands via SSH. Is there any way to do this? Do I need any static routes or a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ProxyJump/-J commandline option (if your openssh supports it):

```
ssh -J 22.22.22.22 10.10.10.30
```

or setup a DNAT on 22.22.22.22:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 22.22.22.22 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.30:22
```

and connect to specific port:

```
ssh -p 2222 22.22.22.22
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `ssh -J PROXY`, as was answered by @Tomek, you can use `ProxyJump` and `ProxyCommand` in your `~/.ssh/config` file to simplify connections on the command line.  This has been covered elsewhere, including [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1253960/replace-proxyjump-in-ssh-config/1254668)

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host ServerB
    User USERNAME
    Hostname 22.22.22.22
    Port 24


Host ServerC
    User USERNAME
    Hostname 10.10.10.33
    Port 24
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p ServerB
```

Then connect to the `Server C`:

```
ssh USERNAME@ServerC
```